# Drawing two semicircles with labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw two semicircles with their centers aligned. I also want to add a label below each of them.

[image]

I quoted my working example below in which I draw two circles, and I tried to clip them using "\clip" command to get semicircles. Is there any other and better way to do this directly (drawing these two semicircles with their labels)?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,float}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,thick] (0,0) circle (1);
\draw[blue,thick] (3,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it: put an `arc` in your path. `arc`s are a little bit tricky:

- first, like in turtle plots, navigate the "pen" to its starting point
- second, draw the arc from start to end angle
- angles are in degree, with 0° starting on the x-axis, 90° being the y-axis and so on.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red,thick] (1,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=1cm]; 
    \draw [blue,thick] (3,1) arc [start angle=90, end angle=270, radius=1cm]; 
    
    \node at (1,-1.5) {your label here};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{The caption of your heart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Let's further look at the arc by varying the radius at its starting point, to see how it works.

[image: variation]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red,thick] (1,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=1cm]; 
    \draw [red,thick] (1,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=.5cm]; 
    
    \draw [blue,thick] (3,1) arc [start angle=90, end angle=270, radius=1cm]; 
    \draw [blue,thick] (3,1) arc [start angle=90, end angle=270, radius=.5cm]; 
    
    \node at (1,-1.5) {your label here};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{The caption of your heart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```